# Succinct way in Ruby to manipulate this string

Tags: ruby

Sometimes I like learning how to do things the "Ruby" way. I was wondering - what is the most succinct, yet readable way to take a string such as:

`foo-bar`

and manipulate it to read:

`Foo Bar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"foo-bar".split("-").map(&:capitalize).join(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

```
"foo-bar".gsub(/\b(\w)/){|m| m.capitalize}.sub '-', ' '
```

Comment: This leaves the hyphen in the result.

Comment: fixed schoolboy error, thanks. Incidentally, I ran both versions through Benchmark and the split + map was significantly quicker than gsub + regex, even on longer strings, which I found surprising. Generally, any string operation I've done in other languages is dealt with most efficiently via regex, but not in Ruby. (I was using 1.9 with Onigurama)

Answer (score 0):

```
>> p "foo-bar".scan(/\w+/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
"Foo Bar"
=> "Foo Bar"
>> p "foo---bar".scan(/\w+/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
"Foo Bar"
=> "Foo Bar"
>> p "foo 123 bar".scan(/\w+/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
"Foo 123 Bar"
=> "Foo 123 Bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "foo-bar"
"foo-bar".split("-").map(&:capitalize).join(" ") # edited to because former answer was not optimal
```